# Getting url part after a button click

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
   echo "<td><a href='book.php?id='".$row['id'].">Book</a></td>";
}
```

In the book.php page I would like to get the id="something"'s something that was parsed in the url. Could someone help me ?

Book.php

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id']; // this is not right
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: `"<td><a href='book.php?id='".$row['id'].">Book</a></td>";` something is wrong here, and this seems to be fine `$id=$_GET['id'];`.

Comment: Look at the HTML output.  It's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing with this

```
echo "<td><a href='book.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Book</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want current page url use the function below

```
function CurrentPageURL()
{
 $pageURL = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
 $pageURL .= $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' ?     
 $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] :   
 $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 return $pageURL;
}
```

You you are concerned only about parsing the querystring then this link may help you

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php